# Going back two UIViewControllers using segues

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, segue

In my iOS app, I have four `UIViewController`s, and for the sake of argument let's call them 1, 2, 3, and 4. I have segues leading from one to the next progressively (1->2, 2->3, 3->4). However, in 4 I want there to be a button that can segue back to one. I only pictured one way of doing this, but I couldn't figure out how to implement it...

This way would be to have a segue directly connecting 4->1, and when the segue is called delete 2 and 3 from memory (otherwise the user could keep building up `UIViewController`s since none of them are being removed). I don't know how to delete them from memory since I don't have any variables pointing to them (that is, they were created when their respective segues were called, so as far as I know I don't have direct access to them).

I don't know if that's the best way, but if you can figure out how to do that (or a better way), any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a UINavigationController if you aren't already.

Then in your 4th view you just need a button with a selector that does the following:

```
- (IBAction)goBackToFirstView:(id)sender {
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

This will handle all your memory for you and send you back to the first view controller by popping everything else off the stack.

Comment: If all he is wanting to do is go back to the first one, then yes. This is how you should do it. If, however, he wants to be able to hit the back button and go to view controller #4 again, then this won't do that.

Comment: "You need to use a UINavigationController..." should I only be using one? I've added one for every `UIViewController` I've added to my storyboard…

Comment: He's stated he wants to go 1->2->3->4->1

Comment: Yes you should only have ONE UINavigationController for this simple setup.

Comment: yeah Ryan is correct, this is meant for a "game over" scenario, taking the user back to the beginning screen, with no desire to go back to the "game over" screen

Comment: wait so I have a UINavigationController for the root view, and then it will take care of everything?

Comment: Thats correct. One UiNavigationController then each view pushes the next view on the stack.

Comment: Hey so now I'm getting an error that reads: "No visible @interface for 'UINavigationController' declares the selector 'popToRootViewController'

Comment: Actually never mind, I figured it out… the selector name is actually `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)`

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:navigation.viewControllers.count-1]];
    navigationController.viewControllers = array;
```

Then perform the segue.

Comment: Would you like to provide some insight into why it is a bad way?

Comment: You really should manually manage your UINavigationControllers child viewControllers in this manner. You should use the built in functions for popping, pushing, and such. 

Reason being even though you're removing the objects from its control, that doesn't necessarily release them and could end up leaving the actual viewControllers in memory while the navigationController loses its pointers to them.

Comment: I didn't mean to sound rude with my first comment. Was just stating I don't think its a good way to handle things. Sorry for the way it sounded.

Comment: No problem, we're all friends here :)

As I understand it, though, the view controllers are retained by the navigation controller. When they are removed from it, even manually, they are released.

Comment: In the new and improved ARC world of iOS5 you are probably right actually.